# Magento2 controllers doesnt work

Tags: magento2, controllers

I would like to create own controller with own frontend view.

Here are my files:
**registration.php:**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Unity_CheckOrder',
    __DIR__
);
```

**controller:**

```
namespace Unity\CheckOrder\Controller\Index;

//use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
//    protected $_resultPageFactory;
//
//    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
//    {
//        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
//        parent::__construct($context);
//    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo '<p>You Did It!</p>';
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
       // $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
       // $resultPage->addHandle('check_order');
      //  return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Of course  I tried also with:

```
namespace Unity\CheckOrder\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
//        echo '<p>You Did It!</p>';
//        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->addHandle('check_order');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Unity_CheckOrder" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkorder" frontName="checkorder">
            <module name="Unity_CheckOrder" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**view/frontend/layout/checkorder_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <title>
            Simple Magento 2 Module
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Unity\CheckOrder\Block\Test" name="checkorder" template="Unity_CheckOrder::checkorder.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

view/frontend/templates/checkorder.phtml

```
<?php $this->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?>
```

**block test.php**

```
<?php
namespace Unity\CheckOrder\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getHelloWorld()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

I also tried with

```
<?php
namespace Unity\CheckOrder\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getHelloWorld()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

After go to url magento2test.localhost/checkorder/  and magento2test.localhost/checkorder/index/index/

I got 404 all the time.
Of course  I tried :

- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean / flush`
- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Module is enabled and visible in Admin Advanced tab

Here is structure of my module:
[image]

Comment: Did you tried with `http://localhost/checkorder/`? You should try with ` http://localhost/yourmagento/checkorder/`

Comment: localhost = mymagento. To be honest it is http://magento2test.localhost/checkorder/

Comment: have you added `router.php` controller?

Comment: No. Is it necessary? Isn't Router.php used for handling CMS pages? It sets module name (module front name) to “cms”, controller name (controller path name) to “page” and action name to “view”   – app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Page/View.php controller.   How should it help?

Comment: Can you show your folder structure or the full path of file?

Comment: Sure, add to main post

Comment: Your `registration.php` is wrong. It should be under `Unity/CheckOrder/resgistration.php`

Comment: To be honest, registration.php is under Unity/CheckOrder/resgistration.php.. I spent hours for debuging and I just missed that Controller is outside Unity/CheckOrder... Nvm, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I see your controller is outside also. ha..ha.. I will put an answer. That help our community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We should make sure that our controllers, blocks, config, registration files are inside our module folder**. In your case, seem that your controller is wrong place.

Comment: registration.php was inside module. Controller was outside, however moved Controller into module resolve problem ^^

Comment: Yes, I have just edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a stupid question, but did you also enable the module? `bin/magento module:enable Unity_CheckOrder`. I once was pulling my hair out for almost an hour simply because I forgot to enable the module :-/

Comment: Yes, module is enabled in app/etc/config.php